# Условие для цикла

Tags: java

Есть список с картинками, он перемешивается, и при нажатии на кнопку он проходит по списку от начала до конца.

Как задать условие в цикле последней в списке картинке, чтобы на ней смогла появится надпись?

Мой код:

```
Button but1;

int i = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);

        final ArrayList < Integer > ts = new ArrayList < > ();
        ts.add(R.drawable.ts1);
        ts.add(R.drawable.ts2);
        ts.add(R.drawable.ts3);
        ts.add(R.drawable.ts4);
        ts.add(R.drawable.ts5);

        Collections.shuffle(ts);

        but1.setBackgroundResource(ts.get(0));

        but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                i++;
                but1.setBackgroundResource(ts.get(i));
                if ( ? ? ? ) {
                    but1.setText("конец");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Это весь мой код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ((ts.size - 1) == i){
    but1.setText("конец");
}
```

В данном случае, `ts.size`,  мы запрашиваем размер созданного вами массива. Вы добавили в него 5 элементов. Вычитаем из этого размера 1, так как переменная `i` у вас начинается с 0. Вообще в массивах принято запрашивать элемента с 0. Первый элемент будет `ts.get(0)` и так далее.

Соответственно когда размер массива минус 1 выравнится с `i` который у вас увеличивается, условная конструкция вернет `Истину`. В кнопку установится требуемый текст.

Comment: Огромное спасибо,это работает!долго ломал голову,но так и не смог найти решение,даже стыдно и обидно за себя

Comment: @Владимир: а мне стыдно просить вас проставить галочку если ответ вам помог.

Comment: Да я только рад её поставить.и ещё,если не сложно,можете на словах прокоментировать ваш ответ,что бы я лучше понимал,что я делаю,я просто только начал осваивать программирование

Comment: @Владимир: обновил ответ

Comment: Да,теперь я всё понял,ещё раз огромное спасибо